# Number type in mongoose schema always get saved as string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, express, mongoose

I have this simple schema, with contact as Number data type. Strangely, the input data(contact) always gets saved as string in mongodb. I have no idea, as to what is happening in the background, or am I missing something.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var memberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
.
. Other fields are not shown/ necessary 
.
contact: {
   type: Number,
   required: true,
   }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Member',memberSchema);
```

In my routes file, I send user data for adding into DB like this

```
exports.post = function(req,res,next){
    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.contact)
        return res.render('index', {error: 'Fill Name, Email and Contact'});
    //req.body.contact = parseInt(req.body.contact);
    var member = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        contact: req.body.contact
}
```

As you can see req.body.contact is whatever user has entered in a form and I pass it that way.

The problem is, either I am not understanding the actual concept or there must me something more to it.
Note: I am not using any express or mongoose validator middlewares.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Specifying `type: Number` should be all you need to have Mongoose store `contact` as a number, so something else is going on here. Can you update your question with a [MCVE]?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was a mistake from my end. I was counting the length of Number i.e., Phone Number should be <= 10. instead of value.length <= 10, it should be value.toString().length <= 10.

Answer (score 2):

You could test the contact value against a regular expression. The following example shows a custom validator using a regular expression to validates against a 10 digit number. Custom validation is declared by passing a **[validation function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate)**:

```
var memberSchema = new Schema({
    contact: {
        type: Number,
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                return /d{10}/.test(v);
            },
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid 10 digit number!'
        }
    }
});

var Member = mongoose.model('Member', memberSchema);

var m = new Member();

m.contact = '123456789';
// Prints "ValidationError: 123456789 is not a valid 10 digit number!"
console.log(m.validateSync().toString());

m.contact = 0123456789;
// Prints undefined - validation succeeded!
console.log(m.validateSync());
```

Comment: I think you are using the node-mongoose-validator module. That’s why I am getting this error “Validator failed for path `contact` with value `7894532109`”. I am currently not using the validator module, instead doing it with a straight approach. With Validator module, we can always use isNumeric.

Comment: only need to do this line: return /d{10}/.test(v);

Replace by:   return /\d{10}/.test(v);

In case Mongoose not accept number begin with 0 you can change the type: String

Comment: I guess some countries have contact number shorter than 10. so if we are accepting international users then i guess appropriate regex should be `/d{7}/.test(v);`